# MySQL - searching a self join and ranges or data

Tags: mysql, search, join, indexing

I'm tasked with my local community center to build a 'newlywed' type game in time for Valentines day, so no rush!

So, We've got 50 odd couples who know each other quite well are going to be asked 100 questions before time. Each question has the users response and a range at which allow a margin of error (this range quota will be limited). and they can then select what they think their partners answer will be, with the same range for margin of error.

EG (I'll play a round as me and my GF):

Question: Do you like fruit?
I am quite fussy about fruit so I'll put a low score out of 100.. say 20. But what I do like, I LOVE and think that my GF might think I will put a higher answer, so my margin of error I'll allow is going to be 30.
I think she loves fruit and will put at least 90.. but she enjoys alot of foods so may just rank it lower, so I'll give her a margin of 20.

Ok, repeat that process for 100 questions and 50 couples.

I'm left with a table like this:

u_a = User answer

u_l = user margin of error level

p_a = partner answer

p_l = partner margin of error level

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `large` (
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_q` int(11) NOT NULL,
`u_a` int(11) NOT NULL,
`u_l` int(11) NOT NULL,
`p_a` int(11) NOT NULL,
`p_l` int(11) NOT NULL,
KEY `id_user` (`id_user`,`id_q`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Stackoverflow Test';
```

So my row will be in the previous example:

(1, 1, 20, 30, 90, 20)

my mission is to search ALL users to see who the best matches are out of the 50.. (and hope that couples are good together!).

I'll want to search the DB for all users where my answer for my partner matches their answer, but for every user.

Here's what I've got so far (Note I've commented out some code, that's cause I'm trying two ways, not sure what's best):

```
SELECT
match.id_user,
count(*) as count
from `large` `match`
INNER JOIN `large` `me` ON me.id_q = match.id_q
WHERE
me.id_user = 1 AND
match.id_user != 1 AND
GREATEST(abs(me.p_a - match.u_a), 0) <= me.p_l
AND
GREATEST(abs(match.p_a - me.u_a), 0) <= match.p_l 

#match.u_a BETWEEN GREATEST(me.p_a - me.p_l, 0) AND (me.p_a + me.p_l)
#AND
#me.u_a BETWEEN GREATEST(match.p_a - match.p_l, 0) AND (match.p_a + match.p_l)

GROUP BY match.id_user

ORDER BY count DESC
```

My question today is :

This query takes AGES! I'd like to do it during the game and allow users a chance to change answers on the night and get instant results, so this has to be quick. I'm looking at 40 seconds when looking up all matches for me (user 1).

I'm reading about DB engines and indexing now to make sure I'm doing all that I can... but suggestions are welcome!

Cheers and PHEW!

Answer (score 0):

Your query shouldn't be taking 40 seconds on a smallish data set.  The best way to know what is going on is to use `explain` before the query.

However, I suspect the problem is the condition on `me`.  The MySQL engine might be creating all possible combinations for all users and *then* filtering you out.  You can test this by modifying this code:

```
from `large` `match` INNER JOIN
     `large` `me`
     ON me.id_q = match.id_q
WHERE me.id_user = 1 AND
      match.id_user != 1 AND . . . .
```

To:

```
from `large` `match` INNER JOIN
     (select me.*
      from `large` `me`
      where me.id_user = 1
     ) me
     ON me.id_q = match.id_q
WHERE match.id_user != 1 AND . . . .
```

In addition, the following indexes might help the query:  `large(id_user, id_q)` and `large(id_q)`.

Comment: I was experimenting with more users and more questions to really make it bullet proof.. I just realized that my test table is over 15 millions rows!!! The geek in me wants to make it work still... I should probably get over that...

Comment: @Beertastic . . . Are you doing Valentines Day for an entire country?  Is your community center planning massive acquisitions, say to take over the world?  LOL  In that case, 40 seconds isn't so bad.  And, you learned something about developing test scripts (hint:  `truncate table` is very useful).

Comment: You're right... i've just truncated and am making 50 users of 100 q's each.. quick as a flash!